# Should I use all actions before buying anything?

Tags: dominion

For example, I have this hand. 3 coins, one market, one library. So first I play the market, then buy something with the coins (plus 1 coin from the market) and then play the library **having nothing in my hand because I already used the coins and the market** (so I draw seven cards or even more). Is that right?

Comment: In addition to the correct answer below; you seem to be misunderstanding a few things. You CANNOT play treasure cards in your action phase; you must wait until your buy phase. Also, you don't "buy things with Copper". Copper is a card that, when played, produces coin/money that you can spend, just like Market and Woodcutter do. In your buy phase, you play whatever treasure cards you want, then add up all coin you've produced this turn (from treasure cards + action cards), then buy what you want.

Comment: @GendoIkari As an edge case, [Black Market](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Black_Market) allows you to play treasure cards in the action phase.

Comment: @PhilipKendall So does Storyteller, but it didn't seem necessary to mention edge cases like this when explaining the very basics.

Comment: @GendoIkar, thanks I do know that, I have played Dominion more than 20 times. I just wasn't sure about the buy and action phase order particularly in this case.

Comment: @8odoros: Remember *ABC*: Action phase, then Buy phase, then Cleanup phase.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the rules:

> "The player must complete all of his Actions before
>   he moves on to the Buy phase of his turn."